# Why does button of type submit trigger OnInit in the parent component

Tags: c#, forms, components, eventemitter, blazor

Having a `parent` and a `child` component ,the `child` has a form with 2 buttons, one of type `submit` and the other of type `button`.Both their `onclick` handlers invoke `Actions` for the parent to respond.
In the parent component after it handles the `event` sent from the child,the event triggered by the `submit` button also triggers `OnInit` on the parent.
Why does this happen ?

Example:

**Parent**

```
<Child onsubmit=@((value)=>OnSubmit(value)) 
       oncancel=@((value)=>OnCancel(value))></Child>
@functions()
{ 
  private int x=3;
  protected override void OnInit()
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"From OnInit ,x={this.x}");
  }
  protected override void OnAfterRender()
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"From AfterRender,x={this.x}");
  }
  protected void OnSubmit(int _x) 
  { 
     //lets say child sends x=7
     this.x=_x;
     Console.WriteLine($"From handler, x={this.x}");
  }
  protected void OnCancel(int _x) 
  { 
     //lets say child sends x=7
     this.x=_x;
     Console.WriteLine($"From handler, x={this.x}");
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
   <form>
    <button type="submit" onclick="@(()=>OnPressSubmit())">Trigger submit</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="@(()=>OnPressCancel())">Trigger cancel</button> 
    <form>
    @functions()
    {
     [Parameter] protected Action<int> onsubmit{get;set;}
     public void OnPressSubmit()
     {
       this.onsubmit?.Invoke(7);
     }
     [Parameter] protected Action<int> oncancel{get;set;}
     public void OnPressCancel()
     {
       this.oncancel?.Invoke(7);
     }
```

When i run this code, in the console i will see that `variable` is indeed set in the eventhandler `OnEvent`,however it is then  resetted in the `OnInit`.

**OUTPUT** (for the button of type `submit`)

```
From Handler,  x=7  //in parent eventhandler
From OnInit, x=3
From OnAfterRender, x=3
```

**OUTPUT** (for the button of type `button`)

```
From Handler,  x=7  //in parent eventhandler
From OnAfterRender, x=7
```

Why does the `submit` button trigger also `OnInit` on the parent **AFTER** the parent handles the event ?

Comment: Is this the correct order of the output? From Handler,  x=7  //in eventhandler
From OnInit, x=3
From OnAfterRender, x=3

Comment: Yes ,first it assigns correctly then , the page refreshes.Is it normal for the `parent` page to do a total refresh when the `child` tag closes? The child is in the parent based on a conditional `@if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: 
Add a StateHasChanged(); method like this:

```
protected void OnEvent(int _x) 
  { 
     //lets say child sends x=7
     this.x=_x;
     // If this works, then it is a bug with Blazor...
     // If not, be patient...
     StateHasChanged();

     Console.WriteLine($"From handler, x={this.x}");
  }
```

If the page refreshes, then the output is correct: Whenever you reload the page, it is as if you run it for the first time. Now you should find out why the page refreshes. Show your code...

To your other question: Re rendering in Blazor occurs with components whose state has changed as a result of events (StateHasChanged() is implicitly called by Blazor), or when you explicitly call the StateHasChanged() method. The re-rendering is done only by components affected by a state change, thus a child component may re-render while its parent won't.

Edit: From what you've said below, we now know why the page is reloaded, 
      and thus, every time you click the submit button, the value of x is 3.
      Of course, when you click on the other button, the parent component is   not re-rendered, but as I've already demonstrated above, if you add a call to the StateHasChanged() in the OnEvent method, the parent component will re-rendered, and the x variable will contain 7.

Note: You should not use button with the type attribute set to "submit". Blazor is an SPA framework. You must not post form data by submitting the form  (method="post") or setting the type attribute of button to "submit". You should use Ajax (HttpClient) instead. As far as I know, Blazor prevents submission of forms: Perhaps only forms with method="post" and a submit button.

Hope this helps...
Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you out

Comment: I should have stated that my `Child` is a form with the 2 buttons : 1 of type `submit` and the other of type `button`.They both launch events to the `parent`.The one of type `button` does not trigger `OnInit` on the `parent`.